# Problem with Ajax [ Trying to update Add to cart without refreshing the page ] - Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use ajax to handle the Add to cart functionality and show total quantity without [return back()] which is the current state .. or the need to refresh the page

I tried the following ;

in all_courses.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
     $(document).ready(function() {

             $('.ajaxPOST').click(function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();

                   var url = $(this).find('#url').text();
                   var courseId = $(this).find('#courseId').text();

                    var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();


                    $.ajax({
                            
                            method:"POST",
                            url:url,

                            data:{_token: _token, id: courseId},

                            success:function(data,status,XHR){

                                 alert(data.totalQuantity);

                                 var totalQuantity = data.totalQuantity;

                                 $('#totalQuantity').text(totalQuantity);
                            },
                            error:function(xhr,status,error){
                                alert(error);

                            }

                    });

             });

     });
</script>
```

```
@foreach ($courses as $course)
<div>
<h5 class="card-title">{{ $course->crs_title}}</h5>

<a href="#" class="ajaxPOST btn btn-default add-to-cart">
<div id="url" style="display:none">
{{ route('AddToCartAjaxPost') }}
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="courseId"> {{$course->id}} </div>
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>

</div>

@endforeach
```

In my CoursesController.php

```
   public function addToCartAjaxPost(Request $request){


     $id = $request->input('id');

     $prevCart = $request->session()->get('cart');
      $cart = new Cart($prevCart);

      $course = Course::find($id);
      $cart->addItem($id,$course);
      $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);

       return response()->json(['totalQuantity',$cart->totalQuantity]);

  }
```

in my Web.php

```
//Add to cart using ajax post request
Route::post('courses/addToCartAjaxPost', ["uses"=>"CoursesController@addToCartAjaxPost", "as"=> "AddToCartAjaxPost"]);
```

in my app.blade

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="{{route('cart')}}">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">CART
@if(Session::has('cart'))
<h2><span id="totalQuantity" class="badge badge-light">
QTY {{ Session::get('cart')->totalQuantity }} | Total {{ Session::get('cart')->totalPrice }} EGP
</span></h2>
<span class="sr-only">Items</span>
@endif
</button>
</a>
</li>
```

Now what happens is, first I get response, Unidentified .. and the items actually gets added to cart, but only appear on page refresh .. so the button actually adds the item to cart on click. but I have to refresh the page for the updates to happen.

what is missing here ?

Comment: Hi does  `$('#totalQuantity').text(totalQuantity);` showing any value ?

Comment: Hello @Swati .. No the response shows [ Unidentified ] .. but when I refresh the page, the item quantity and total price gets updated and appear on the cart icon.

Comment: Also this `alert(data.totalQuantity)` shows nothing ? Did you check your backend if `$cart->totalQuantity` has right value ? As you are returning `json` data you need to use `dataType: "json"` or parse json return using `JSON.parse(data)`